# How to display column chart in SSRS with all categories not condensed?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I'm new to SSRS development and, one of the chart that I'm working with is to display all categories based on a dataset.

This is my dataset text query

```
    select m.PIServerID, m.MetaData1 as Station, t.[State], count(t.[State]) StateCount
from MasterTags m inner join TagStates t on t.ID = m.StateID
where m.PIServerID in (@SystemName) and t.[State] = @State and m.MetaData1 is not null
group by m.PIServerID, m.MetaData1, t.[State]
```

where, `@SystemName` and `@State` are report parameters.

In the report (as seen on the screenshot below), the tag count by station chart doesn't look good.  The columns are too thin, pointing arrows everywhere and xAxis categories label are not readable.

[image]

This chart has the below Size properties.

[image]

Is there a way to make the chart paginated or resize dynamically based on the data rendered (specifically the xAxis categories)?

I'm not quite sure if this has been raised before or someone already had a solution.  But, I can't find any similar situations which the report displays all the chart categories without an issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I had a similar problem with my chart, I resolved it by setting in the chartarea in the axis the interval and intervaloffset.

Comment: @Raphael, are you referring to the properties of xAxis?  What would be the value of interval and intervaloffset?

Comment: Exactly i refer to that parameter. I calculate the interval dinamically. I see now a possible problem, i thought tha on the x axis you had some dates non your stations. if you set the interval for example = 10 you'll see one station name out of 10, and I imagine that's not correct.

Comment: @Raphael I'm sorry but I don't get it.  Is it possible you provide an answer so that I can follow and start from there?  Thanks